# String Format with undefined number of characters c#

Tags: c#, string, string-formatting

So I'm working on formatting a string and I need to line it up in a table, but this string has an undetermined number of characters. Is there anyway to have the string be in the same spot for each column? so far I have:

```
ostring +=  "Notes\t\t" 
+ "       :  " 
+ employees[number].Notes 
+ "\t\t" 
+ employees[number].FirstNotes 
+ "\t\t" 
+ employees[number].SecondNotes;
```

I use a similar fashion on the other rows, but they have a pre-determined number of digits, this however doesn't so I can't use the string modifiers like I would like.

Any ideas on what I need to do?

Comment: If you absolutely must line them up correctly AND the size is unknown, the only thing you can do is iterate over all the values and find out what the maximum size is.

Comment: What is the table you are putting the data into, a html table?

Comment: can you use List view to display this..//

Comment: its a table that i am lining up to print out, right now im using messagebox to see how the formating is going and this is the last problem that i have run into

Comment: Remember, you should use a fixed width font to have your string correctly aligned. With fonts with proportional width you will have hard times to align anything (the size for character `i` will not be the same for character `w`)

Comment: Below, serveral solutions were given; however, keep in mind that they will only work if you display the text using a monospace font like Courier New or Consolas.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`String.PadRight()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.padright.aspx) to force the string to a specific size, rather than using tabs.

Answer (score 2):

When you are using [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) item format has following syntax:

```
{ index[,alignment][ :formatString] }
```

Thus you can specify alignment which indicates the total length of the field into which the argument is inserted and whether it is right-aligned (a positive integer) or left-aligned (a negative integer).

Also it's better to use StringBuilder to build strings:

```
var builder = new StringBuilder();
var employee = employees[number];
builder.AppendFormat("Notes {0,20} {1,10} {2,15}", 
    employee.Notes, employee.FirstNotes, employee.SecondNotes);
```

Answer (score 0):

You would first have to loop over every entry to find the largest one so you know hoe wide to make the columns, something like:

```
var notesWidth = employees.Max(Notes.Length);
var firstNotesWidth = employees.Max(FirstNotes.Length);
// etc...
```

Then you can pad the columns to the correct width:

```
var output = new StringBuilder();
foreach(var employee in employees)
{
    output.Append(employee.Notes.PadRight(notesWidth+1));
    output.Append(employee.FirstNotes.PadRight(firstNotesWidth+1));
    // etc...
}
```

And *please* don't do a lot of string "adding" ("1" + "2" + "3" + ...) in a loop. Use a `StringBuilder` instead. It is much more efficient.

Comment: im trying to use the .pad right method but its not working im still getting the same as i was before here is what im doing: ostring += "Notes\t\t" + " : "; var output = new StringBuilder(); output.Append(employees[number].Notes.PadRight(24)); output.Append(employees[number].FirstNotes.PadRight(34)); ostring += output + employees[number].SecondNotes; ostring += Environment.NewLine

Comment: Your original question does not say what you had before, so I don't know how else to help you.